# Using max/min functions to remember highs/lows in dynamic data in Google Docs

Tags: max, google-docs, min

Within Google Spreadsheets, how can I retrieve the max and min values of a cell containing dynamic data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DMAX and DMIN

https://support.google.com/docs/bin/static.py?hl=en&topic=25273&page=table.cs

Comment: Thanks for your response.I would like to determine the max and min values of a cell in my Google spreadsheet. The value of this cell is dynamic; it is constantly updated over the course of the day.

I was advised to use the function DMAX and DMIN.

However, I am unsure of the preceding step. Should I first create a database that is appended with the most recent cell value and then request the max/min?

If yes, how would I create it?

Thanks in advance.